# Asynchronicity, and variable overrides in Cypress

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, cypress

My question is, how do you override the variable in the async function which is out of the scope of this?
I read [here](https://benohead.com/blog/2014/12/02/javascript-variables-asynchronous-callback-functions/) that the problem is the lack of a callback. After adding the callback, the variable outside the scope in which it was changed (but still the variable itself is in the correct scope) returns "undefined". What am I doing wrong?

Test:

```js
const savedVariableCallback = (variable) =>
  console.log(`Variable saved ${variable}`);

describe(() => {
      ...
      it("Sample input type", () => {
         let fixValue;
         cy.fixture("example.json").then(({ email }) => {
            actionsPage
            .selectSampleInput()
            .then((input) => {
               checkAmountOfElements(input, 1);
               checkVisiblity(input);
            })
            .type(email)
            .then((input) => {
               checkIfValue(input, email);
               fixValue = "Nice work";
               savedVariableCallback(fixValue);
            });
         });
         cy.log(`fixValue is: ${fixValue}`);
     });
})
```

I expect the first log to show `Variable saved Nice work` and the second log to show `fixValue is: Nice work` for variables. But for now, I get in the first log `Variable saved Nice work` but in second I get `undefined`.
I want to have that variable to be accessible in `it()` method scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Since the reference didn`t work I suggest approaching it with an [allias](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Sharing-Context)

```
const savedVariableCallback = (variable) =>
    console.log(`Variable saved ${variable}`);

describe(() => {
...
    it("Sample input type", () => {
        cy.fixture("example.json").then(({ email }) => {
            actionsPage
                .selectSampleInput()
                .then((input) => {
                    checkAmountOfElements(input, 1);
                    checkVisiblity(input);
                })
                .type(email)
                .then((input) => {
                    checkIfValue(input, email);

                    let fixValue = "Nice work";
                    savedVariableCallback(fixValue);
                    cy.wrap(fixValue).as('fixValue')
                });
        });
        cy.get('@fixValue')
            .then(fixValue => {
                cy.log(`fixValue is: ${fixValue.value}`);
            })
    });
})
```

Comment: Hmmm, still I get undefined in that second `cy.log()`. It's changed as you did.

Comment: did it cahnge in the execution of the function savedVariableCallback ?

Comment: No, it console log proper variable `Variable saved Nice work`

Comment: I edited my answer with another approach.

Comment: hmm a little bit complex, but it's working so thanks :) I hope there is also another shorter idea for this or way so if I use this in many places this variable I don't need to do `get` method all the time

Comment: If someone else shares such a way I would be delighted. Cypress is like allergic to normal variables :)

Comment: "Cypress is allergic to normal variables" - very poetic!

Answer (score 0):

If you change

```js
cy.log(`fixValue is: ${fixValue}`)
```

to

```js
console.log(`fixValue is: ${fixValue}`)
```

you can see the order of logging

- fixValue is: undefined
- Variable saved Nice work

so `cy.log()` ***grabs the value*** of `fixValue` at the time the command is added to the queue, that is before `cy.fixture()` has run, even though it actually runs after the `cy.fixture()`.

You can defer it until `cy.fixture()` is complete by adding another `.then()`

```js
cy.fixture("example.json").then(data => {
  ...
})
.then(() => {
  // enqueued after the fixture code
  cy.log(`fixValue is: ${fixValue}`)     // now it sees the changed value
})
```

but of course everything downstream that needs to use `fixValue` must be inside the `.then()` callback.

You can also defer the "grabbing" of the value

```
cy.then(() => cy.log(`fixValue is: ${fixValue}`))
```

or split `cy.fixture()` into a `before()`, which will resolve the variable before the test begins

```js
let fixValue;

before(() => {
  cy.fixture("example.json").then(data => {
    ...
    fixValue = ...
  })
})

it('tests', () => {
  cy.log(`fixValue is: ${fixValue}`)     // sees the changed value
})
```

Comment: but what if I want to use variables in another test/part of the test without nesting everything in one `then`? I know it's a bad pattern from the ISTQB perspective. What I gave was a simple example. In real life app, we generate data in input in one of the tests (so before can't be used), but then we use it across the test file. Same principles - I get something from request, want to save it to a variable but then I can't use it because saving variable was called inside `then`

Comment: LOL, that's life in the Asynchronicity world. In most of those scenarios you mention there, you will not have a problem.